# Itext : Split row issue

Tags: java, itext

I facing an issue with Itext, a row is cut between two pages. My code work like this :

```
PdfPTable Master = new PdfPTable(1);
Master.setHeaderRows(1);

PdfPTable Header = new PdfPTable(1);//create header table
//fill header
PdfPCell HeaderCell = new PdfPCell();
HeaderCell.addElement(Header);
Master.addCell(HeaderCell);//add header in master

foreach result in query
{
    float[] colsWidth = { 4f, 9f, 5f, 8f };
    PdfPTable Content = new PdfPTable(colsWidth);//create content table
    //fill content
    content.keepRowsTogether(0);
    PdfPCell ContentCell = new PdfPCell();
    ContentCell.addElement(Content);
    Master.addCell(ContentCell);//add header in master
}
document.add(Master);
```

But in the PDF document some Content table are split between two pages (and so, some of Master Table rows).
I try to add :

```
Master.keepRowsTogether(0);
Master.setSplitLate(false);
```

with no effect.

I also tried :

```
Master.setSplitRows(false);
```

But this make the cut row simply disappear.
Someone know how to disable row split in Master table ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable the wrap also in the cell that will be splitted

```
ContentCell .setNoWrap(false);
```

So

```
foreach result in query
{
    float[] colsWidth = { 4f, 9f, 5f, 8f };
    PdfPTable Content = new PdfPTable(colsWidth);//create content table
    //fill content
    content.keepRowsTogether(0);
    PdfPCell ContentCell = new PdfPCell();
   ContentCell .setNoWrap(false);
    ContentCell.addElement(Content);
    Master.addCell(ContentCell);//add header in master
}
```

and don't forget `Master.setSplitLate(false);`

Comment: I tried but unfortunately this doesn't work as written, so I tried different way and this worked by adding 'Master.keepRowsTogether(0)', so thank you FevPlr.

Answer (score 0):

This works for itextsharp 5

TableName.SplitLate = False